# WP User Query & wp-admin/admin-ajax returns 0 with data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a odd problem and i'm hoping one of you could guide me to the answer. I am new to PHP and JQuery, so i'm not really sure what is causing this, but essentially, I have a ajax call for a custom search field that works. The "problem" is that after every search result it returns a very random '0' after the results. So for example if I do a search, i'll get something like:

```
Stack Overflow 0
```

I've tried seeing what has caused it in the code but I can't iron it out, and as far as I can tell it just...randomly appears there. I don't mind it showing up, if I had a way to apply a css class to it so I could hide it. Anyways, here's my code:

```
    $args = array(
        'role' => 'artist',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'display_name',
        'meta_query' => array(
           
        )
    );

    if (isset($_POST['artistFilter'])){
        $name = explode(" ",$_POST['artistFilter']);

        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'first_name',
            'value' => $name[0],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'last_name',
            'value' => $name[1],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    };

    if (isset($_POST['mediumType'])){
        // WP_User_Query arguments
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'meta_key' => 'artist_medium',
           'value'=> esc_attr($_POST['mediumType']),
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    };


    if (isset($_POST['locationType'])){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'meta_key'=>'studio_region_location',
            'value' =>$_POST['locationType'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    };

    $user_query = new WP_USER_QUERY ($args);

    if (! empty($user_query->get_results())){
        foreach ($user_query->get_results() as $user){
            $artistimage = get_field('primary_image', 'user_' . $user->ID);
            echo '<div class="artistSearchColumn">';
            if ($artistimage){
                echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '"><img src="' . esc_html($artistimage['url']) . '" alt="Test"/>';
                echo '<p>' . $user->first_name. ' ' . $user->last_name .'</p></a>';
            }
            else {
                 echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '">' . esc_attr($user->first_name) . ' ' . esc_attr($user->last_name) . '</a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h1>No Users Found.</h1>';
    }
```

my jquery:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    var ajaxscript = {ajax_url: './staging/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'}
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Finding Artists...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
    </script>
```

Replacing $('#response').html(data) with anything besides data will not return the 0, so I feel like tis related to that.

Thank you for any help!!!

Comment: _“i'll get something like:”_ - that doesn’t tell us too much, because that is only what it looks like, after it has been interpreted as HTML already. Please go check what the actual response to your request looked like in your browser dev tools (network panel), and show it.

Comment: Hey CBroe, it's the same thing:

```
Stack Overflow

0
```

Comment: But you are creating a whole HTML structure there, `<div class="artistSearchColumn">` etc. That can hardly have resulted in plain text only?

Comment: It does, strangely. This is what the jquery returns:

```

<div class="artistSearchColumn">
<a href="linkhere">
<div class="artistBGImage">IMG HERE</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
0
```

It's very very odd lol. 

Here is the raw response:

```
<h2>No Artists Found.</h2>0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I have to kill the PHP function manually. I simple added

```
die();
```

to the end of the script and it doesn't return the 0. Yay! :)

```
 if (! empty($user_query->get_results())){
        foreach ($user_query->get_results() as $user){
            $artisttour = get_field('artist_tour_status', 'user_'.$user->ID);
            if ($user->artist_profile_display == 'Yes'):
                if ($artisttour != 'Not on Tour'):
                    $artistimage = get_field('primary_image', 'user_' . $user->ID);
                    echo '<div class="artistSearchColumn">';
                    if ($artistimage){
                        echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '">';
                        echo '<div class="artistBGImage" style="background: url(' . esc_html($artistimage['url']) .');">';
                        echo '<img src="https://monadnockart.org/wp-content/plugins/foo/arttour25-2020icon-2.jpg" alt="'.esc_html($user->user_login).'s Artist Profile"/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<p>' . $user->first_name. ' ' . $user->last_name .'</p>';
                        echo '</a>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '"><p>' . esc_attr($user->first_name) . ' ' . esc_attr($user->last_name) . '</p></a>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                else:
                    $artistimage = get_field('primary_image', 'user_' . $user->ID);
                        echo '<div class="artistSearchColumn">';
                        if ($artistimage){
                            echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '">';
                            echo '<div class="artistBGImage" style="background: url(' . esc_html($artistimage['url']) .');">';
                            
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<p>' . $user->first_name. ' ' . $user->last_name .'</p>';
                            echo '</a>';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<a href="/staging/author/' . esc_html($user->user_login) . '"><p>' . esc_attr($user->first_name) . ' ' . esc_attr($user->last_name) . '</p></a>';
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                    
                endif;
            else:
                echo '';
            endif;
            }
        }
    
    else {
    echo '<h2>No Artists Found.</h2>';
        }

        die();
}
```